# Add multiple dependencies of Maven project into a non-Maven project in Java

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to add the Maven dependencies of a Maven project into a non-Maven project. However, there are too many and adding them one by one would be too tedious. Could someone suggest a shortcut to add them all at once?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following maven command in the main directory of your maven project:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Then you will be able to find all of the downloaded jar files of your dependencies here:

> {PROJECT-MAIN-DIRECTORY}/target/dependency/

You can add the *-DoutputDirectory* parameter to have the jar files placed somewhere else.
Afterwards you may simply add the jars to the build path of your non-maven project.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by adding dependencies to a non-maven project?

If you want to make it a maven project, right-click the project and in *configure* click *convert to maven project*. Otherwise, you can copy-past the jars into your build path. If you have the other maven project in your computer, you can locate the jars in .m2 folder in your user directory and add them to the project or download them one by one.